# Eclipse Project Properties not showing Spring Option

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new in spring framework. Actually my context assistant is not working in case of  `<context:component-scan base-package="" />` i.e.
its not showing any predictions. I got ans from someone that you have to change it in to `project>properties>spring>Bean support` but I am not able to find spring option in project properties.
PFA

[image]

Comment: Are you using maven? If yes, check your dependencies and run Update Project

Comment: Are you sure you have the necessary plugins installed? Eclipse does not support Spring out of the box. If not, install the "Spring Tools" via Marketplace or just use [Spring STS](https://spring.io/tools), which is an Eclipse distribution customized for Spring.

Comment: OK. I havne not installed Spring tool and STS , Thank you @VinkoVorih